# Unable to Display Audio and Video on Mobile Browsers using Raspberry Pi with uv4l-webrtc

Tags: python, ios, streaming

I have set up a streaming server on my Raspberry Pi (CM4) using UV4L and a USBCAM. The command to start UV4L I used is as follows:

```
uv4l --syslog-host localhost --driver raspicam --encoding h264
```

I have also implemented HTTPS using OpenSSL.
The webrtc works perfectly on desktop browsers like Safari and Chrome, but I am facing issues with iOS browsers, specifically Safari and Chrome. The audio and video does not display properly, and only the MJPEG stream (without audio) is visible.

I tried adjusting the UVC driver and raspicam, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I also tried changing from HTTPS to using ngrok, but it still doesn't work.

I have been searching for a solution for a long time but haven't been able to find one. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or improvements to resolve this issue.